# My BB app isn't retrieving data from google feed api

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, google-feed-api

I develop an app using jQuery Mobile.
After compilation, i tested on BB simulators but non is able to display data of the feed.
How  do i configure my config.xml file to achieve this.
Below is my current config.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" version="1.0.0" rim:header="RIM-Widget: rim/widget">
    <name>on the Go!</name>
    <description>Get latest information on the Go!</description>
    <content src="index.html" rim:allowInvokeParams="true"/>
    <author href="" rim:copyright="Copyright 2013" email="josiahaccounts@gmail.com" xml:lang="en" its:dir="rtl" >Josiah Gerald</author>
    <access uri="http://ajax.googleapis.com" subdomains="true" >
        <feature id="blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments" />
        <feature id="blackberry.app" />
    </access>
    <rim:loadingScreen 
        backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        backgroundImage="images/news.png"
        foregroundImage="theme/images/ajax-loader.gif"
        onRemotePageLoad="true"
        onLocalPageLoad="true"
        onFirstLaunch="true">
        <rim:transitionEffect type="fadeIn" duration="300" />
    </rim:loadingScreen>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <rim:cache disableAllCache="true" />
    <rim:connection timeout="60000">
        <id>TCP_WIFI</id>
        <id>MDS</id>
        <id>BIS-B</id>
        <id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
        <id>WAP2</id>
        <id>WAP</id>
    </rim:connection>
    <license>(c) 2013 www.mobilenizer.com</license>
    <icon src="images/icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

Here is the solution:

```
<access uri="http://ajax.googleapis.com" subdomains="true" />
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0">
        <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
    </feature>
```

So rather than nesting the feature inside the access, i separated it.